# How to use PaperScript.compile/execute/load manually?

Tags: paperjs

I included paperjs to my wordpress site with the wp-enqueue function. Unfortunately I cannot use paperscript directly. So I started using javascript directly. However, since I am trying to use the voronoi example (http://paperjs.org/examples/voronoi/) on my site and it has a lot of the paperscript magic math operators I am wondering how I can inject paperscript code manually into javascript.

I discovered the PaperScript.compile and so on methods, but didn't figure out how to use them.
Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
paper.install(window)
window.onload = function() {
var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
paper.setup(canvas);
var theScript = PaperScript.compile(`
var voronoi =  new Voronoi();
//...
`);
```

I also tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Paperscript.execute(`
//code
`, window);
</script>
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: I find it quite easy to convert paperscript to javascript. That said ; I think you should be able to use paperscript noramlly in your wordpress if you include paper.js properly before executing your paperscript (`<script type=text/paperscript`>).

Comment: How to convert this line from paperscript to js?:
`var point = new Point(i, j) / new Point(size) * view.size + col / 2;`

Comment: replace all the operators by the corresponding functions: `new Point(i, j).divide( new Point(size).multiply(view.size)).add(col/2)` (you will have to check the priorities of the operators though ; it should be correct but since this line has no parenthesis it is a bit ambiguous)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xidi2xidi/sx5d7re2/) demonstrating the solution.
You should be able to adapt it to your own use case quite easily.

```js
paper.setup('canvas');

const code = `
    new Path.Circle({
        center: view.center,
        radius: 50,
        fillColor: 'orange'
    })
`;

paper.PaperScript.execute(code, paper)
```